# Mitigate the perfomance reduction between a mysql query with a single condition and with an 'OR' condition

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a job queue running many jobs a second.  A change in the code has meant that the job queue has slowed down to an unacceptable level. The culprit seems to the 2nd of the two following queries.  My question really is, are there some obvious solutions regarding indexing or the way the query is structure to reduce the execution of the 2nd query so it is only marginally slower than the first?

My first MySQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT JobID FROM sysJobQueue WHERE JobStatus = 1 AND QueueID IS NULL
```

(Query took 0.0005 seconds.)

My second MySQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT JobID FROM sysJobQueue
    WHERE (JobStatus = 1 OR JobStatus = 6)
      AND QueueID IS NULL
```

(Query took 0.0043 seconds.)

Comment: I can see that changing this to:

 "...JobStatus IN (1, 6)..."

gets it to  (Query took 0.0015 seconds.)

Comment: to get the best answers, edit your question to show output of `select version();`, `show create table sysJobQueue;`, and output from `explain select...` for both queries

Comment: If that `SELECT` returned 100 rows, I would not be surprised by the 4.3ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

UNION is the fastest way to combine results.

```
SELECT JobID FROM sysJobQueue WHERE JobStatus = 1 AND QueueID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT JobID FROM sysJobQueue WHERE JobStatus = 6 AND QueueID IS NULL
```

As Rick James poimts aout you need a INDEEX ON (QueueID, JobStatus) so that the serve3r can find the right vlaues faster, a combined index is here recomended. But i am guessing that you alredy hav a INDEX

Comment: And specify the index(es) that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Both queries would benefit from

```
INDEX(QueueID, JobStatus)   -- in this order
```

Notes:

- `(JobStatus = 1 OR JobStatus = 6)` is interpreted as `JobStatus IN (1, 6)`.  Any timing differences are caused by the wind direction changing.
- `IS NULL` is treated as an `=` test for optimization purposes.
- For `WHERE ... AND ...`, you should put the column in the `=` test first before `IN` and before any range test in the `INDEX`.  The order in the `WHERE` clause does not matter.
- Yes the `UNION` trick is often a good one for optimizing `OR`, but it is overkill *in this case*.  `UNION` becomes especially beneficial if the component Selects can benefit from *different* indexes.  (Not the case here.)
- Timings under 10ms should not be trusted.  Or at least you should not read anything into 0.5 < 4.3.  Too many things could be causing the reproducible difference.
- For digging into fast queries, looking at the Handler counts is quite reproducible and relatively reliable:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts
- "Don't queue it, just do it".  If the processing time if not much longer than the enqueue+dequeue time, you are better of simply processing the items.
- If something hiccups and the queue gets backed up with a thousand pending actions, all sorts of things can add to the backup.  For example, the Delete may suddenly take a minute to run.  Or the Deletes coming from multiple workers could deadlock.